# ¿Cómo comprobar si un programa se está ejecutando? - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Buen día, les comparto esta duda:
Lo que pasa es que tengo un programa la cual cada vez que detecte un cambio en un fichero con un tipo de archivo específico, se ejecuta un .exe...
Lo que pasa es que si detecta movimiento varias veces seguidas, se vuelve loco el programa la cual se va a ejecutar y se dañaría el flujo del programa.

¿Hay alguna manera para comprobar si el programa se está ejecutando, y en el caso que lo esté haciendo no se ejecute?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {

                FileSystemWatcher monitor = new FileSystemWatcher
                {
                    // Path = @"C:\Users\yersson.hernandes\Desktop",
                    Path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\701Server",
                    // Filter = "*.xls",
                    Filter = "*.msg",
                    IncludeSubdirectories = false

                };
                WaitForChangedResult result =
                monitor.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed);
                //Trace.WriteLine("Se ha detectado movimiento con los archivos de excel");
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.UseShellExecute = true;
                info.FileName = "robot.exe";                
                info.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";               
                Process.Start(info);                           
            }
        }
```

Gracias por leer y su apoyo.

Comment: Podrias crear una variable de tipo Bool, que una vez lea la linea que ejecuta el programa  cambie a True (?

Answer (score 1):

Para impedir que una aplicación se ejecute dos veces, aparte de comprobar los procesos en ejecución, puedes utilizar este código:

```
internal bool CheckPreviousApplicationOpen()
{
    const string GuidApplication = "Mi identificador de aplicación";
    bool createdMutex = false;

    // Intenta crear un mutex con el Guid de la aplicación
    // Si no se puede crear el Mutex es porque ya había una aplicación abierta
    try
    {
        _mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, GuidApplication, out createdMutex);
    }
    catch {}
    // Devuelve el valor que indica si existe una aplicación abierta
    return !createdMutex;
}
```

Este código intenta crear un [objeto mutex](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netcore-3.1) en el sistema. Sólo puede haber un identificador de ese tipo con el mismo nombre en todo el sistema, por tanto, la segunda vez que se intente crear dará un error porque no podrá generarlo. Así te aseguras que nunca se ejecutan los dos a la vez.

Por supuesto, la constante `GuidApplication` debe tener una cadena única para tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Quiza agregando esto antes del Proccess.Start(info) pueda ser de utilidad:

```
Process[] instancia = Process.GetProcessesByName("NombreExe");
        
        if (instancia.Length > 1)
        {
            //Exe Corriendo
        }
        else
        {
            //correr exe
            Process.Start(info);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

si quieres saber si hay un programa corriendo en el PC, la forma es la siguiente:

```
// Obtiene todos los procesos en ejecución
Process[] allRunningPrograms = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Con eso tendrías un array con todos los procesos en ejecución. de los cuales puedes extraer el nombre, el id,... Ahora, si quieres filtrar o saber sólo si un programa concreto se está ejecutando, entonces puedes hacer:

```
// Obtiene los procesos en ejecución del programa pasado como parámetro
Process[] myProgram = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

Y ahora si quieres hacer que deje de ejecutarse, sería tal que así:

```
if (myProgram.Length > 0) 
   myProgram[0].Kill();
```